# How to pass a turn to AI in a game?

Tags: android, android-imageview, multiplayer

I am writing a simple game for 2 players, where they have to make turns after each other - select a few objects to remove from the board (removing is actually setting an `ImageView` invisible), then a player presses "End turn" at the end to pass the turn to another player.

The board is a `GridLayout` with the `ImageView`s, all `ImageView`s have `onClickListener()`, and they are all visible at the beginning of the game. A player clicks on several `ImageView`s (at these moments their IDs are placed in an array) and then clicks "End turn", this array of his move is analyzed, the corresponding `ImageView`s are set to invisible, and after that the turn should be passed to another player (the array is cleaned and the number of the current player changes).

All objects on the board have `onClickListeners()` attached. Upon clicking, their IDs are placed in an array, and a variable contains the number of the current player. The turns are switched in `onClick()` method on a `onClickListener()`, attached to the "End turn" button, and it's simply cleaning the array of the IDs and updating the number of the current player.

It works fine for the case of 2 humans playing (on the same device). But if a person plays with the computer, the AI calculates and makes its move in the same `onClick()` method. Since the user interface updates only after processing the `onClick()`, (`ImageView`s are set to invisible, and so on), AI's moves are not drawn on the screen and the player sees as if after his move (clicks on the objects), the board was redrawn immediately with the added changes made by the computer's move (objects removed).

So, I need to pass the turn to AI somehow differently, not in `onClick()` of the "End turn" button to be able to draw the AI's selection and hide selected views - before the player can make his next move. **But how to do that and where?**

`onClick()` method for the "End turn" button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    hideSelectedImageViews();
    if (currentGame.isWinningState()) {
        //you won
    } else {
        changePlayer();
        if (playWithAI) {
             calculateAImove(currentGame);
             showSelectedImageViewsByAI(); //doesn't work even with .invalidate()
             hideSelectedImageViews();
             if (currentGame.isWinningState()) {
                  //AI won
             }
             changePlayer();
        }
    }
 }
```

In `showSelectedImageViewsByAI()`, a specific image resource is set for the `ImageView`s, so that they will look differently ("selected").

Comment: Posting your code/processes/diagram/drawing, would be helpful.

Comment: Post your code please. Try to .invalidate() the "board"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new `Thread` where it will run the AI's moves, when the AI makes their selections you can make the thread delay some seconds (so their selection can be shown) and then remove them. Your code has that problem, once the AI makes a selection, it's removed instantly (even if you did `invalidate()` twice)

If you are not familiar with Threads here is an example:

```
//I assume your code was inside an Activity
public class mainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable
{
    Thread aiThread;

    /*...*/

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        hideSelectedImageViews();
        if (currentGame.isWinningState()) { /*you won*/ } 
        else 
        {
            changePlayer();
            if (playWithAI) 
            {
                aiThread = new Thread(this);
                aiThread.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        calculateAImove(currentGame);
        showSelectedImageViewsByAI();
        Thread.sleep(1000); //This will make thread wait for 1 second before removing selected (note the number is in milliseconds)
        hideSelectedImageViews();
        if (currentGame.isWinningState()) { /*AI won*/ }
        changePlayer();
    }
}
```

Please note that when using a thread to influence the UI you shouldn't affect views directly, you should instead call `view.post()` instead, if you are unfamiliar with either `Threads` or the `view.post()` method I recommend  searching online for them.

Comment: Your idea was very useful for me, I implemented it as an AsyncTask: before execution it sets the button "End turn" invisible, executes calculations and publishes progress in the UI Thread, setting the necessary ImageViews "selected" with a delay. In onPostExecute() method the ImageViews hide in the UI Thread and the player is changed. This allowed me not to write any manipulations with the threads manually. Thank you for the answer!